# Why do layers appear in the wrong order in QGIS 2.2?

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, order

I have a problem with in which order my vector and raster layers appear in QGIS. I have raster that I want to be the background of my other layers (vector). I place the vector layers on top in the TOC, but some of them still end up under the raster layer in the display?
I have check there projection and that's the same for all layers. I have also tried putting the raster layer on top in the TOC, but the resault is still the same.

I just want to show a few vector layers on top of a raster, but in this version something goes wrong. I have never had any trouble with this in earlier version of QGIS.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rightclick on a layer, and check `Update Drawing Order`. Prior to QGIS 2.0, this was part of the Table of Content.

Sometimes it helps to save and open the project again.

Comment: There is a also a panel for setting the layer order. View panels.  Then there is a toggle to have layer order managed separately to tree order.

Comment: A question on this, in order to have the layer order on display to be the same as tree order, which panels should be activated? At the moment the only one I have active is 'layer'.

Comment: If the checkbox is set according to my answer, the layer order is identical to tree order. If you uncheck Drawing order, you can use the `layer order` panel. Or check `Control rendering order`on that panel. It unchecks the `Drawing order` automatically.